# hidden(?) process is taking 20GB of RAM Ubuntu

Tags: memory, ps, htop

I have a PC with 64 GB of RAM in my work. I am noticing that there is something that is taking a lot of my memory, sometimes 20 GB or even more than 40 GB. I could not find which process is responsible for that using `top` or `htop`. I tried also using the suggestions in this link.

None of them worked. So far I was not able to track which program is triggering this. I run MATLAB on this computer, using pieces of codes that can take 20 or 40 GB, but supposedly after I close the program, the memory should be released. I accessed this computer via SSH from Windows 10 this weekend to use MATLAB, but I closed it before closing the SSH session.

I heard that sometimes programs that crash may not release the memory they are using, but I have no idea of how to free this memory now.

Something that I also find odd is that when I use `htop`, it runs quite slow when this memory is taken. It take several seconds to process each command I give, like sorting the processes by % of memory. The only thing that worked so far is restarting the computer. But the hard disk is encrypted and I cannot restart it remotely, so I need to wait when I come in front of it, which is not always possible. Besides, while I am accessing this computer remotely I might need maybe 90% of the 64 GB of RAM.

Following a suggestion from a user from another forum, I paste here a recent set of memory check. Right now it is taking 20GB without apparent reason. Here is the output:

```
$ps xua --sort -%mem | head -20

USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
cayo        2493  0.5  0.9 4535480 643612 ?      SNsl Nov16  17:44 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
cayo        4507  1.0  0.7 5064236 476568 ?      Sl   Nov16  31:15 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=12489594871761196763,14569705314115548721,131072 --enable-features=UsernameFirstFlow --lang=en-US --enable-crash-reporter=, --extension-process --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=14 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files
cayo        3121  0.0  0.5 3024512 356900 ?      Sl   Nov16   0:20 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
cayo        4228  0.8  0.5 1039056 347068 ?      SLl  Nov16  27:33 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
cayo        4310  0.5  0.4 1572332 276192 ?      Sl   Nov16  16:41 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --field-trial-handle=12489594871761196763,14569705314115548721,131072 --enable-features=UsernameFirstFlow --enable-crash-reporter=, --gpu-preferences=MAAAAAAAAAAgAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAA= --shared-files
cayo      328586  0.0  0.3 1245240 213464 ?      Sl   Nov17   0:50 evince /home/cayo/Dropbox/SHARC_Manual.pdf
cayo       66800  0.0  0.2 1602744 187080 ?      Sl   Nov16   1:19 evince /home/cayo/Dropbox/molpro_2019_manual.pdf
cayo      295144  0.0  0.2 4760688 186336 ?      Sl   Nov17   0:55 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=12489594871761196763,14569705314115548721,131072 --enable-features=UsernameFirstFlow --lang=en-US --enable-crash-reporter=, --extension-process --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=567 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files
cayo      572898  0.8  0.2 8947928 185188 ?      Sl   13:17   0:08 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=12489594871761196763,14569705314115548721,131072 --enable-features=UsernameFirstFlow --lang=en-US --enable-crash-reporter=, --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=849 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files
root         502  0.1  0.2 251700 181960 ?       S<s  Nov16   5:18 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
gdm         2034  0.0  0.2 3981684 181072 tty1   Sl+  Nov16   1:09 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
cayo      575117  3.9  0.2 4780680 163852 ?      Sl   13:27   0:19 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=12489594871761196763,14569705314115548721,131072 --enable-features=UsernameFirstFlow --lang=en-US --enable-crash-reporter=, --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=866 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files
cayo      295027  0.0  0.2 4710288 163824 ?      Sl   Nov17   0:10 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=12489594871761196763,14569705314115548721,131072 --enable-features=UsernameFirstFlow --lang=en-US --enable-crash-reporter=, --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=562 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files
cayo      304946  0.0  0.2 4725024 163512 ?      Sl   Nov17   0:18 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=12489594871761196763,14569705314115548721,131072 --enable-features=UsernameFirstFlow --lang=en-US --enable-crash-reporter=, --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=591 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files
cayo      307875  0.2  0.2 4759024 161492 ?      Sl   Nov17   4:11 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=12489594871761196763,14569705314115548721,131072 --enable-features=UsernameFirstFlow --lang=en-US --enable-crash-reporter=, --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=634 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files
cayo      309837  0.1  0.2 8916036 158696 ?      Sl   Nov17   1:34 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=12489594871761196763,14569705314115548721,131072 --enable-features=UsernameFirstFlow --lang=en-US --enable-crash-reporter=, --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=649 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files
cayo      324033  0.5  0.2 4695768 143456 ?      Sl   Nov17   7:58 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=12489594871761196763,14569705314115548721,131072 --enable-features=UsernameFirstFlow --lang=en-US --enable-crash-reporter=, --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=679 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files
cayo      309811  0.0  0.2 4689916 142408 ?      Sl   Nov17   0:56 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=12489594871761196763,14569705314115548721,131072 --enable-features=UsernameFirstFlow --lang=en-US --enable-crash-reporter=, --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=648 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files
cayo        2516  0.7  0.2 2138092 141080 ?      Sl   Nov16  22:28 /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/TeamViewer
```

If I sort by `rss` or `share` I get basically the same processes on the output.

As far as I understand, there is nothing here that explains 12 GB of memory being used somewhere, that makes even using `htop` slow. If I take the first 30, they sum up to 6%, which should be about 4GB.

Thank you a lot for any suggestion on how to free this memory or finding what is taking it.

---

Results from `top`:

```
top - 17:09:55 up 2 days,  7:38,  1 user,  load average: 0.49, 0.53, 0.54
Tasks: 32764 total,   1 running, 32763 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.9 us,  4.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  64263.2 total,  25223.8 free,  21777.0 used,  17262.4 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    976.0 total,    976.0 free,      0.0 used.  41425.5 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                
 620146 cayo      20   0   49772  41032   3372 R  76.9   0.1   0:01.22 top                                                                                                                                    
   4507 cayo      20   0 9332100 538308 248716 S   2.6   0.8  38:58.64 chrome                                                                                                                                 
     48 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   1.3   0.0   0:04.66 ksoftirqd/6                                                                                                                            
   4316 cayo      20   0  379760 113120  70444 S   1.3   0.2  19:13.50 chrome                                                                                                                                 
      1 root      20   0  171616  14236   8468 S   0.0   0.0  10:44.97 systemd
```

and results from `df -h | grep tmpfs`:

```
tmpfs                        6.3G  2.3M  6.3G   1% /run
tmpfs                         32G  278M   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                        6.3G   64K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                        6.3G   20K  6.3G   1% /run/user/120
```

Even if I clean the buff/cache with `# sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` nor `# sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` it doesn't take this 20GB out.

I paste also the result of `free`:

```
$ free 
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       65805532    22426248    41734136      342556     1645148    42322332
Swap:        999420           0      999420
```

---

Update: today it is taking 27Gb... The computer was simply left on from yesterday to today without anything else than chrome open.

Comment: Where do you see the number 20 GB? What is measuring the memory when you come to the conclusion that a _process_ (not buffers etc.) is using 20 GB?  Are you sure it's a _single_ process?

Comment: I see 20GB when I use `top` or `htop`. I don't know what it can be related to, although I think it might have a relation with MATLAB. It seems to go increasing. Yesterday it was 12GB, today 20GB (the computer was left on from one day to the other, and with just a some terminals with ssh session and what is shown in `ps` output

Comment: There is nothing in the question showing a missing 20GB. Show us, don't tell us.

Comment: I can see where the confusion about what's using the memory comes from, as I can't see it either (I'm no Linux user though). However, you still have in excess of 40 GB free according to the `free` output. Simply having something using up memory would not make the system slower (why would you even have that amount of RAM in the machine in that case?).

Comment: If you're talking about the `used` number from `free` that one includes memory used from disk cache, and it's natural for that to go up. Because this is unnecessarily unobvious and other reasons I rolled my own `ps` + `top` replacement which is supposedly easier to understand, using `px` and `ptop` may or may not help you: https://github.com/walles/px#ps-and-top-for-human-beings

Comment: Kusalananda, It does not make the system slower. What becomes slow is `htop`. This machine is used for work in theoretical quantum chemistry, where I often run codes that stores up to 500GG of data in the memory. Something higher than 60GB I obviously run in clusters. Johan Walles, I downloaded your program and it didn't help, there is nothing that sums up to 20GB of RAM. Although I find strange that using `ptop` does not show RAM use as in the second line of the first screenshot of your link.

Comment: @CayoEmilio I'm also experiencing this one! Did you fix it? Thanks

Comment: Hello Goper, no, sorry... I eventually finished my work and didn't use this machine anymore. Just to answer @Kusalananda, this machine was used for very heavy simulations in physiscs, and we had to deal with matrices that could reach more than 40GB of RAM...

Comment: Facing similar situation on ubuntu 22. Around 20GB memory is being used even without running any app.